# How using Lookup in SSRS get the ratio based o Year and Month from different datasets

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, lookup

I have two tables in SSRS 2010 from two different datasets.How can I calculate ratios based on values for each year and month? In excel its pretty easy, one cell divide by another cell. But how achieve this in SSRS?
[image]

Trying to use lookup function but it doesnt go very well so far.

Tables are in a group in SSRS
[image]

And Totals
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a third matrix to the report, make the Dataset for the that matrix match the name of the dataset you used for the second matrix. Or, you can simply copy and paste the second matrix, and move it below the others. Then use this expression to do the calculations.

```
=Fields!PaidLoss.Value / Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & Fields!AccidentMonth.Value, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthStartRisk.Value, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1")
```

You will have to adjust the field names since I can’t see all of then names in the screen cap. Adjust the dataset name as well. Format the number to show as a percentage. (0%)

You are concatenating the year and month to get a proper lookup here. That should make it work. You may have to play around with this is it doesn’t work right the first time.

Good luck!

**EDIT:**
Possible total expression (not tested!):

```
=Sum(Fields!PaidLoss.Value) / (Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 1, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 1, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 2, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 2, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 3, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 3, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 4, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 4, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 5, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 5, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 6, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 6, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 7, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 7, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 8, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 8, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 9, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 9, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 10, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 10, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 11, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 11, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1") + 
    Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & 12, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & 12, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, but maybe you also give me some advise how to deal with totals in this case?  I though its gonna be easy, just add `SUM` at the beginning of the `Lookup` but it doesn't give me correct result. 

`=SUM(Fields!PaidLoss.Value) / SUM(Lookup(Fields!AccidentYear.Value & Fields!AccidentMonth.Value, Fields!YearStartRisk.Value & Fields!MonthStartRisk.Value, Fields!EarnedPr.Value, "DataSet1"))`

Comment: I added a possible solution for this. The only other thing that could maybe work is adding 2 more datasets that roll up the totals by year that you could lookup from. I didn't think about the totals before. It's getting ugly! :)

Comment: Just tried that. The idea is good, but unfortunately it gives me some random numbers. 
`12440%
177%
45%
51%
11%`

Comment: Im reading about it now, seems like its common issue using `SUM` with `Lookup`

Comment: Yeah, I have seen something about that on SO before too, but I am not finding one quickly. I think some ended up using custom code in the report and the `LookupSet` function. `code.Sum(LookupSet(...))` or something like that.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/salvoz-sql/2013/05/27/sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function/